# can I change ngStyle from other file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I know the basic things in Angular.js and I want to change the background color a page from other page... like a config section 
I mean... I have conf.html and I have two radioButtons, one of them change the background color to Black and the other one change to white color.
I have an other page, home.html, that page I need to change when the user select any of that radioButton options.

This example work but if the radiobuttons change the same page, like this example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle all the modifiers is in the same page.

Some idea? thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, but you could use [local storage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) to remember that `background-color` value.

Comment: Angular itself does not do anything for you to preserve state between navigating from one page to another. You need either [server side technology](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/171203/40625) for that, or something like localStorage as mentioned by @Sam. You should probably read up on those things, and/or edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Thanks @Sam, It was very helpful.